# Why is a wrong link generated while using Migradoc Hyperlink object?

Tags: hyperlink, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have an odd problem while trying to render a Weblink on a PDF using Migradoc.

```
Paragraph hotelP = cell.AddParagraph(offer.Hotel.CompanyName.ToString());
hotelP.AddLineBreak();
Hyperlink hyperlink = hotelP.AddHyperlink(String.IsNullOrEmpty(offer.Hotel.Link) ? "" : offer.Hotel.Link, HyperlinkType.Web);
hyperlink.AddFormattedText(String.IsNullOrEmpty(offer.Hotel.Link) ? "" : offer.Hotel.Link.ToString(), "WebLink");
```

While this renders correctly, the link that it tries to hit is a file link in the file:///...bin/Debug(or Release)/www.theActualLink.org folder of the Project.

Any idea why this is happening? The code snippet should be the correct way of doing this, according to the PDFSharp Forums.

EDIT:
Ok thanks to Thomas, I've changed the code to:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(offer.Hotel.Link))
{
     Hyperlink hyperlink = hotelP.AddHyperlink("http://" + offer.Hotel.Link, HyperlinkType.Web);
     hyperlink.AddFormattedText(offer.Hotel.Link, "WebLink");
}
```

This is not the final code, but it now works because of the "http://" prefix on the link.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does offer.Hotel.Link include "http://" or "https://"? This could make the difference.

What's the point of calling `AddHyperlink()` when the URL is empty?

Comment: No, it's usually just www.link.com. And that was the problem. It needs the http:// prefix to actually work. I can now try and find a way to check for dumb user input and add or omit the prefix accordingly.

Thanks for the tip. I've updated my question with the final code.